# Verify if a WMS layer exists or not in GeoServer (OpenLayers3)

Tags: openlayers, wms

```
WMSsource = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/alger_data/wms',
        params: {
            'LAYERS': 'alger_data:hotel'
        },
        serverType: 'geoserver',
        crossOrigin: "Anonymous",
        outputFormat: "application/json",
    })
});

map.addLayer(WMSsource);
```

Comment: Do a GetCapabilities

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: OpenLayers has a WMS Capabilities parser https://openlayers.org/en/v3.20.1/examples/wms-capabilities.html  Once you have a JSON object you can create a simple JavaScript function to search through it, for example for layers named "Temperature" https://jsfiddle.net/fx5h124p/